# How to code in Python to convert .vpp to .xml?

Tags: python, xml, visual-studio-code, visual-paradigm

How to convert .vpp file of visual paragdim to xml in code of python ?

i cant find the api for it and tired parsing .vpp file by xml package but it did not work please help out as i need to do is as soon as possible it is my project work and i cannot seem to find any solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [this document](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/export-and-import/exporting/exporting-xml/#:~:text=Select%20Project%20%3E%20Export%20%3E%20XML%E2%80%A6%20from%20the,%28s%29%20to%20export%20only%20their%20content.%20Click%20Export.) help?

Comment: By the way, you added the label for vscode. May I ask where it is involved in the problem？

Comment: i added a imported the xml file and tried converting it it gave me an error saying its not supported by xml

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have access to api and have to use python, you could use
[pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to extract it from a GUI like explained in the [docs](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/124/218/6848_exportingxml.html)

just be careful while using it with differents resolution cause you have to pass the right position to do an action, but you should be fine if follow the docs.

Comment: ill try it and let you know

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).